Understanding the Uniqueness of Extremals in Gelfand and Fomin's Calculus of Variations
In "Calculus of Variations" by Gelfand and Fomin, there is a statement that I’m having trouble understanding:

If in such a case there exists only one extremal satisfying the boundary conditions of the problem, this extremal must perforce be the curve for which the extremum is achieved."

This is found in the context of discussing Euler's equation, which provides a necessary condition for an extremum but not a sufficient one.
My confusion lies in the assertion that if there’s only one extremal that satisfies the boundary conditions, it must necessarily correspond to the extremum. Why does the uniqueness of the extremal imply that it achieves the extremum? Couldn’t there be other curves that satisfy the boundary conditions but don’t yield the extremum?

Think of a mountain you may pass left or right with stationary paths in fixed time but different lenghts and velocities.
If one unique extremal path exists only, it must by a minimum for positive quadratic forms of velocities. There is no upper bound of the mean kinetic energy by velocity to $ \infty$ and delaying start time until time is nearly over.

Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand Gelfand & Fomin's claim. They are basically saying that if we have a unique critical point, then it must be an extremum. But I don't see why. Take for instance the real valued function $x\mapsto x^3$. It has a unique critical point, but certainly not an extremum.

No access to that book, From teaching experience, Euler-Lagrange.Hamilton is working on a Riemann manifold with a positive bilinear form on the tangent space aka velocities, disturbed by a gauge term of potentials,   resulting from a translation in momentum space $$p=\nabla_{\dot x} L \mapsto p + A(x)$$. The potentials have to be bounded relative to the metric term $ G(x)(p,p)$ in the momentum subspace. Thats one of the difficulty with singular potentials, where $-1/r$ is a natural bound. Starting point of 'Analysis of Operators' in QM: Self adjointness, Limit point vs Limit circle.
